# Nextjs compiling error- Module not found: Can't resolve 'module'

Tags: javascript, next.js, node-modules

I'm working on a nextjs project with wagmi hooks. Nextjs threw `Can't resolve 'module' error` (see error message below). Note this is after I surpressed the initial 'cannot resolve fs module' and 'child_process module' error by adding fallback statement in my next.config.js file.

I'm using wagmi hooks to read and send transactions to deployed smart contracts. I wonder if this threw the chain of the error messages. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Error message:
`./node_modules/eslint-config-next/index.js:42:0 Module not found: Can't resolve 'module'`

Reference code in /eslint-config-next/index.js:42:0

```
const mod = require('module')
const resolveFilename = mod._resolveFilename
mod._resolveFilename = function (request, parent, isMain, options) {
  const hookResolved = hookPropertyMap.get(request)
  if (hookResolved) {
    request = hookResolved
  }
  return resolveFilename.call(mod, request, parent, isMain, options)
}
```

My next.config.js:

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
/**below is added to suppress initial fs module not found and child_process module not found error*/
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (!isServer) {
      config.resolve.fallback.fs = false;
      config.resolve.fallback.tls = false;
      config.resolve.fallback.net = false;
      config.resolve.fallback.child_process = false;
    }

    return config;
  },
  future: {
    webpack5: true,
  },
  fallback: {
    fs: false,
    tls: false,
    net: false,
    child_process: false,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "slot_next",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/font": "13.1.2",
    "@nodelib/fs.scandir": "^2.1.5",
    "@rainbow-me/rainbowkit": "^0.8.1",
    "eslint": "8.31.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.2",
    "ethers": "^5.7.2",
    "next": "13.1.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "wagmi": "^0.9.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  }
}
```

I also trie to run `npm cache clear --force` and `npm install` but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution!

you just delete node_modules and package-lock.json then apply following steps

> npm cache clear --force

then

> npm install

I think this help you

Answer (score 0):

Just clear tsconfig.json

then run cmd "yarn run dev" or "npm run dev".

it was worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).